How to replace multiple local backgroup scripts when migrating from Chrome Extension Manifest V2 to V3
am in the process of migrating my Chrome Extention from Manifest V2 to V3.
inside my manifest.json I have an array of local JS like this
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js",
      "js/moment.js",
      "js/uri.min.js",
      "js/functions.js",
      "js/background.js",
      "js/blocked_sites.js",
      "js/banned_words_list.js",
      "js/commonly_used_sites.js"
    ]
  }

For the Manifest V3, its looking for something like this
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
  ...
}

What is the proper way to update this?  Can I minify all the scripts into one service_worker.js?
Any help is appreciated.  thanks!
